# Axios is setting id to zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm getting this issue with get request, this is my axios code:

```
export const fetchNotifications = (id, key) => dispatch => {
  dispatch( fetchNotificationsStarted() );
  axios.get(uri + `/app/notifications/${id}?key=${key}`).then(result => {
    console.log("Axios:",result.data);
    dispatch( fetchNotificationsSuccess(result.data) );
  }).catch(error => {
    dispatch( fetchNotificationsFailure(error.message) );
  });
}
```

I get my array of objects from api, but all objects are setted with {id : 0,...} and this id is an autonumeric field in my sql database. Has this happened to you before? how should I solve it? I need this particular field to make individual requests

console.log output:

> [image: console.log]

Postman api response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-04-23T14:49:47.000Z",
        "title": "...",
        "body": "...",
        "watch": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2021-04-23T15:17:24.000Z",
        "title": "...",
        "body": "...",
        "watch": 1
    }
]
```

My action function:

```
export const fetchNotificationsSuccess = notifs => ({ type : actions.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCEED, payload : notifs });
```

And this is my reducer:

```
    export const reduceNotifications = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
        case actions.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCEED : return ({
          ...state,
          FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : false,
          FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : false,
          FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : true,
          notifications : [...action.payload],
          MESSAGE : ''
        });
        default: return state;
      }
   }
```

Comment: if you are retrieving your api correctly, then the problem lies with your API, not your react codes.

Comment: Did you look in the browser dev tools or some other inspector to look at the actual data coming back from the API? If those are zero then the API is the problem.

Comment: Yes, from postman and browser im getting these fields with their 1, 2 values instead of 0,0

Comment: do you have transform function defined for axios? It's either a transform middleware or a cors problem IMHo

Comment: When you do `console.log("Axios:",result.data);`  the console receives a reference to the object `result.data` and its content won't be read until you click the triangle. So the data shown in the console might have been altered by a **later** step in your code, and does not necessarily reflect its state when you called `console.log`. Replace it with `console.log("Axios:",JSON.stringify(result.data,null,2));` to see the actual data, or set a breakpoint right after the `console.log`

Comment: Ok, using stringify im getting correct id's, but my redux selector stills delivering 0-ids to my components

Comment: Then `axios` itself is not the problem. The reason for the `id` becoming `0` is then somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I have edited above to show every axios -> redux path, im just using useSelector hook in my component like:
const ntf = useSelector(state => state.reduceNotifications.notifications);

Comment: Can you also share the response coming directly from the API?

Comment: I discovered my error, somewhere in my code I was badly using something like this:
const selected = ntf.find(elem => elem.id = selected_id);
fixed with:
const selected = ntf.find(elem => elem.id === selected_id);

Answer (score 0):

I discovered MY error, somewhere in my modal component code I was badly using something like this:

```
const selected = ntf.find(elem => elem.id = selected_id);
```

Mutating everything to zero... easily fixed with:

```
const selected = ntf.find(elem => elem.id === selected_id);
```